# How can I fix the error on Newtonsoft.Json using statement?

Tags: json.net, using-statement

I am working on a .Net console app with c# and I have just added the Newtonsoft.Json using statement but VS code points it out as an error

> The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and suggests I remove unnecessary using statements but it's not unnecessary since I need it for serialization.
Is this a general problem or am I doing something wrong?
[An Image showing the error prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQN7n.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the exception because the compiler could not find the `Newtonsoft` library. You will need to make sure you have installed it and added it as reference. You can do this through [NuGET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) or add the library manually as a refrence.

Comment: Thank you. This was the issue. I installed it in the CLI and it works now.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)